# Does String operation like below uses extra space in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, space-complexity

If I use the following code to remove spaces from the string S, will it be considered as using extra space/memory? Given 'S' string of 'l' length .

```
int n = l
while i < n
    if S[i] == " ":
        S = S[0:i] + S[i+1:]
    n = len(S)
print "the new string ", S
```

*Edit:* This is just a sample code. Please don't comment about its complexity and/or correct way of removing spaces :). The context here was, while solving an algorithm design question, involving some string operation, there was a restriction of using extra space. And I wanted to know operation like this are using extra memory/space or not.

Comment: WHat do you mean by "using extra space"?

Comment: do you _really_ have to do like this to remove spaces from your string? and "space-complexity" tag isn't about algorithms handling space characters...

Comment: Well, it takes O(N^2) time, which kinda sucks.  It does take O(N) space, but so would anything that makes a new string, so I wouldn't call that 'extra'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you do something like `a[b:c]`, Python creates a new object. So yes, you are using extra space. I would suggest using `replace()` method like so:

```
S.replace(" ", "")
```

It will delete all spaces in one go.

And btw, you don't increment `i` in your code and `:` is missing in `while` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the information, really helpful. The missing 'i' increment is because this is just a snippet copied from a larger code, that too not continuous lines of code.